# Click a link to another slide in powerpoint without going full screen

Tags: vba, hyperlink, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

I'm creating a powerpoint which has a contents page, I would like that contents page to have clickable links to other slides in the presentation. The problem is currently those links only work when I go full screen, is there a way which I can click the link without going full screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links only work in Slide Show view.

If you go to Slide Show | Set Up Slide Show, you can choose "Browsed by an individual (window)"

Then the slide show window will be moveable/resizable and won't necessarily fill the screen.

Answer (score 1):

As Steve says Links only work in show mode. To get them to work in edit the only way is to RIGHT CLICK on them and choose Open Hyperlink from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that your presenter(s) aren't putting the deck into slide show mode before they start presenting (meaning your links don't work in normal/edit mode), you could try one of these solutions:

1. Add a solid filled rectangle that fully covers your first slide and set any **Entrance** animation on it with the **Trigger** / **On Click of** set to this shape. Then write the text in the shape "Please press F5 to start this presentation". The shape will never be seen in slide show mode but is a polite reminder for your presenters when they open the .pptx file.
2. Save the deck in the .ppsx file format, forcing it to automatically start in slide show mode.